# How to set global variable in ndoe js that can be accessible in all twig page

Tags: node.js, express, twig

I need to create some variable that can be accessible in all twig template , without add him to all render object in express.

Or i need a methode that add this variable after the controller has finish his traitement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try use `app.locals`

http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#app.locals

app.locals
The app.locals object has properties that are local variables within the application.

```
console.dir(app.locals.title)
// => 'My App'

console.dir(app.locals.email)
// => 'me@myapp.com'
```

Once set, the value of app.locals properties persist throughout the life of the application, in contrast with res.locals properties that are valid only for the lifetime of the request.

You can access local variables in templates rendered within the application. This is useful for providing helper functions to templates, as well as application-level data. Local variables are available in middleware via req.app.locals (see req.app)

```
app.locals.title = 'My App'
app.locals.strftime = require('strftime')
app.locals.email = 'me@myapp.com'
```